# Get all the table names that are available in all the schemas

Tags: sql-server, database

I do not have names of the schema that are available. According to my finding all the queries that i am using are specific to a schema name. I need name of all the tables irrespective of the schema name.
Can anyone help me with that.
I have used the following queries:

1. `SELECT sch.name  AS SchemaName , tbl.name AS TableName FROM sys.tables tbl INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tbl.SCHEMA_ID = sch.SCHEMA_ID ORDER BY tbl.name;`
2. `select * from information.schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';`
3. `select * from sys.tables;`
4. `select * from sysobjects where xtype='U';`

All of these queries are schema specific. If we want to switch between schema we have to use USE %SCHEMA_NAME%. but i need to get all the table names irrespective of the schema name.

Comment: Please share with us the research you have carried out... there are many resources out there which help with this.

Comment: please edit your question with additional information. don't post as comment

Comment: None of those queries are schema specific, if you're using the definition of schema that Microsoft uses. If, on the other hand, you're using the definition of schema that some other database providers use, then what you're looking for are queries that work across *databases*. It would help immensely if you would use the terminology appropriate to the product you're working with.

Comment: *"According to my finding all the queries that i am using are specific to a schema name"* Where did you find this information, as it's wrong. This can be quickly proved wrong with a very simple test: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6283dd71a98f324bbc9768edb0b7aff8)

Comment: i will provide an example to explain myself. I am using MSSQL and there are 3 database schema that are available in it 'SCH-A','SCH-B' and 'SCH-C'. Currently i am connnected to SCH-A, now when i use any of the above provided queries i get a list to tables present in SCH-A, but my requirement is i need to write a query to get all the table name available in SCH-A , SCH-B and SCH-C. NOTE: i do not know all the schema names in advance. I hope my question is clear now

Comment: *"Currently i am connected to SCH-A"* You don't connect to a schema, you connect to a instance and database. If your database has multiple schemas, you will see them all in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `sys` objects unless you have specifically been denied access to them, as I demonstrate in the above fiddle, you can see objects from multiple schemas in the `sys.tables` object.

Comment: Are you talking about databases or schemas? All your claims would be correct, if they had to be related to databases - for schemas they have no sense.

Comment: Apologies , but i meant to say databases

Comment: Can you edit your question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apologies, but i meant to say databases

A database and a schema, in SQL Server, are very different objects. A **schema** is an object within a database, where as a database is on "object" in an instance. The `sys` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects are also database objects and so will only list the objects within the database context they are referenced in.

For example the below 2 examples would both return details of tables in the `MyDB` database:

```sql
USE master;

SELECT *
FROM MyDB.sys.tables;
GO
USE MyDB;

SELECT *
FROM sys.tables;
```

If you want to get the details of tables in every **Database** you'll either need to query them separately, or generate and run a dynamic statement. The dynamic approach would be something like this:

```sql
USE master;
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(30) = @CRLF + N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF;

SET @SQL = (SELECT STRING_AGG(N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(d.[name],'''') + N' AS DatabaseName, t.[name] AS TableName FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.[name]) + N'.sys.tables t', @Delimiter) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.database_id)
            FROM sys.databases d
            WHERE d.database_id > 4) + N';' --skip system databases

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

If you're using an older version of SQL Server, you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` method, rather than `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this query got me the answer that i required.